# mysql select all table data from two tables on two databases

Tags: mysql

I want to get all data from two table on different Databases.I've tried this and only get data from one table.

`Select b1.branch.*, db2.branch.* from db1.branch,db2.branch`

Is there any way to get that?

Comment: That should 'work' are the 2 dbs on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your branch table have the same struct in both database  then you  could use an union  eg:

```
  Select db1.branch.* 
  from db1.branch
  union all 
  select db2.branch.* 
  from db2.branch
```

for obtain both result sets

Comment: what is b1 in  Select b1.branch.*  is it db1

Comment: @MohitKumar  correct  .. thanks for suggestion  .. answer  updated .

Comment: but i used the syntax it shows  
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.